# What is the て-form of みます?

Tags: て-form

I have learned from my previous studies that it is `みんで`.

However, Google translate seems to give me the answer `みて`.

Which is correct?

Comment: Can you explain a little about "previous studies"? Where did you find みんで?

Comment: I had an elective course in my undergrad - Elementary Japanese. So it seems that my teacher was wrong in that aspect.

Comment: You seem to be conjugating it as though it's mim-u rather than mi-ru.  Do you have a basic textbook?

Comment: Yes I do. But it has been some few months before I last opened it.

Comment: May I ask what the down votes were for?

Comment: ^ Dunno. Maybe the downvoters meant to say you should have checked your textbook first?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very basic and does not warrant becoming a question.  It detracts from the overall quality of the forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about [見]{み}ます/見る, the て-form is 見て。

Comment: Is 見ます == watch? If so, then yes, that's what I'm talking about. I'm sorry, I don't understand Kanji yet.

Comment: Yes 見る is to watch. There are other みる as well, but there is no conjugation of みんで. At least, it is not something that I can find in a dictionary like jisho.org

Comment: It is not みて for both みる and みます.

Answer (score 2):

If OP really wanted to make a distinction between みる and みます, then the te-forms would be:

> みる　⇒　みて
>
> みます　⇒　みまして

Comment: Of course, みまして is pretty unusual, but it is technically the -て form of みます.

Comment: How is it used? I'm guessing it's just the polite version of みて. But is there any special nuance in it?

Comment: @Steel If you'd like to know when ～まして would be used (outside of lexicalized phrases like はじめまして), you could perhaps ask a separate question.